# R data.table How to generalize multiple join in loop?

Tags: r, join, data.table, apply, mapply

After many helps I received here, I succeeded to run these next particular joins. Step by step, I'm updating my main DT :

```
DT1 <- data.table(crit = rep(c('AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD'),each = 3),
                  num = rep(1:3, 4), 
                  val = rnorm(12)^2)
DT1

DT2 <- data.table(BB = c(1,3),
                  cross = c(128, 183))
DT2

DT3 <- data.table(DD = c(2,3),
                  cross = c(99, 787))
DT3

DT1[DT2[,  c(.(crit = 'BB'), .SD)] , cross := ifelse(is.na(cross), i.cross, cross), on = .(crit, num = BB)]
DT1[DT3[,  c(.(crit = 'DD'), .SD)] , cross := ifelse(is.na(cross), i.cross, cross), on = .(crit, num = DD)]
```

However, I need to loop, through a `mapply` I think. Something like :

```
mapply(fun.join, DTmain = DT1, DTsec = DT2, MoreArgs = list('BB'))
mapply(fun.join, DTmain = DT1, DTsec = DT3, MoreArgs = list('DD'))
```

But I can not seem to write the correct function fun.join.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What is your desired output? I see a lot of strange code and I have no idea where are you going with it.

Comment: sorry I haven't noticed your answer. I have two main data.table, DT1 and DTX. From DTX, I create many sub DT (DT2, DT3, etc... in my example). Then, I have to join all these sub DT with DT1, in order to update the same column in DT1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
lapply(
  list(DT2, DT3),
  function(dt) {
    dt[
      ,
      c(stack(.SD[, 1]), .(cross = cross))
    ][
      DT1,
      on = .(ind = crit, values = num)
    ]
  }
)
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
    values ind cross       val
 1:      1  AA    NA 0.1287103
 2:      2  AA    NA 2.0288966
 3:      3  AA    NA 0.8914414
 4:      1  BB   128 0.6451096
 5:      2  BB    NA 0.8424112
 6:      3  BB   183 0.3420138
 7:      1  CC    NA 0.4047142
 8:      2  CC    NA 0.7423724
 9:      3  CC    NA 1.3762432
10:      1  DD    NA 0.1086974
11:      2  DD    NA 6.0831923
12:      3  DD    NA 0.5619010

[[2]]
    values ind cross       val
 1:      1  AA    NA 0.1287103
 2:      2  AA    NA 2.0288966
 3:      3  AA    NA 0.8914414
 4:      1  BB    NA 0.6451096
 5:      2  BB    NA 0.8424112
 6:      3  BB    NA 0.3420138
 7:      1  CC    NA 0.4047142
 8:      2  CC    NA 0.7423724
 9:      3  CC    NA 1.3762432
10:      1  DD    NA 0.1086974
11:      2  DD    99 6.0831923
12:      3  DD   787 0.5619010
```

Comment: I was just testing the join solution you gave me yesterday, to see if it would work better. I will give you an update but it seems to work fine !

Comment: @Discus23 I had some typos in my answer, but now they are fixed. Please try the current version.